# How can I change the color of the grout lines in my vinyl flooring?

Tags: linoleum

Between the rectangles of my new lino there are white grooves which I'd like to change into gray color. What's the simplest way to achieve this? Is there a kind of marker I can purchase online for that?

[image]

Comment: honestly the easiest solution is to replace the linoleum with something else you like better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lino is a soft pressed vinyl. Do a test using several different markers on a leftover piece of the flooring. Some markers are pigment based ...don't use those. Use a dye-based marker. Also, many black permanent markers will turn purple. Go to the art store to find a range of permanent markers, then get creative.
Search for "sharpie ingredients" to learn all about'em.

Comment: Thanks. Can't find anything on Amazon when searching "dye markers" though, is there another way to call these that I could use as a keword for search? Or are they rare and can only be found in special shops?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the edge of the vinyl on a sample piece or raise a corner to see if the vinyl itself is grey or black. If it is see if it's not too hard to scratch the white lines off the surface, maybe with a rotary tool guided by a straight edge.

Also consider just replacing it as suggested in a comment.  Modifying it will probably be difficult and yield a bad looking result.

[image]

Comment: It's white unfortunately!